# Yocto: how to make variable recipe for image?

Tags: image, yocto, recipe

I'v got **./meta-mycompany/recipes-fsl/mycompany-image-base.bb** recipe for building image.

Also I have recipes in ./meta-mycompany/recipes-kernel/**driver1** and **driver2** to build alternative drivers. Drivers are for input video. Both of them had in .bb file ***KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD += "${MODULE_NAME}"*** at the end.

Q:How and where (conf/layer.conf probably?) to make load that drivers?
Suppose to use **MACHINE_ESSENTIAL_EXTRA_RDEPENDS** but I need alternative config such way that include **driver1** OR **driver2** but never both - they interferent and anyway it isn't possible to work at the same time on single hardware.
Desired results is to build an **image** with **driver1** included and loaded at boot OR with **driver2**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD += "driver1 driver2"
```

You normally put it into `machine.conf`.

Comment: Thanks I found that way but it's too complicated - that's define different MACHINE variable and most of recipes are failing. Thank you anyway